# How to test tablet apps in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to develop voip app for tablet. I had some questions for developing app in tablets.

- Is it possible to develop voip app in tablet?
- If yes, how to test this app in android emulator?
- Is it possible to make phone calls or internet calls through tablets?
- What is the difference between tablet and fablet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually four questions you have asked
1.) You Can and Can Not be develop a void app, void has many meaning.You can make an app that run only on your device nor on other. Secondly if you are making an effort to deploy an app , you must allow other to use that.To check your void app, Android allows you to check your app directly on your device before launching on Google Play Store.This'll help you to remove bugs, check functionality that lacks on AVD or Emulator

2.) You have install Android SDK on your machine here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

3.) Yes there are many tablet which provide phone call & internet for ex Tab2 , micro max android tab, HTC, etc

4.) Tablet is device where you can run application, play Games, Browser internet and enjoy all the features accept phone calls

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_computer)

Its Phablet not fablet is a device where you have all the benefits of tablet and Phone Call.
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phablet)

Generally we use the term Tablet for all because nowadays all devices come along with phone call facility. Screen ranges from 5-10 inch.

But now Samsung has launched its Phone i.e. Galaxy series in 5 inch Galaxy s1, Galaxy S2 & Galaxy Grand.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong keyword. In first question the word 'void' is replace by 'voip'. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is an app which provide video & audio calling. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip This app is base on XMPP protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP

Answer (score 0):

To test the app in tablet in emulator .

you can select the virtual device manager while creating the exact device as tablet version as u want or else if you want to check in the layout how it will looks then select the type of device showing left to the orientation.